# How to set X509 SubjectAltName (SAN) using Mono.Security?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, ssl, mono

Chrome 58 deprecates self-signed certificates that omit the Subject Alternative Name (SAN).  I use Mono.Security.X509 X509CertificateBuilder() to create a certificate for a Windows OWIN service on 'localhost' that enables the browser to communicate with a TWAIN scanner.  The certificate currently only sets the Common Name so it is insufficient for Chrome 58.

What is the correct way to create a self-signed certificate that enables Chrome to communicate with the OWIN service on localhost, using Mono.Security.X509?

```
    RSA subjectKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);

    X509CertificateBuilder cb = new X509CertificateBuilder(3);
    cb.SerialNumber = GenerateSerialNumber();
    cb.IssuerName = "CN=localhost";
    cb.NotBefore = notBefore;
    cb.NotAfter = notAfter;
    cb.SubjectName = "CN=localhost";
    cb.SubjectPublicKey = subjectKey;
    cb.Hash = "SHA256";

    byte[] rawcert = cb.Sign(subjectKey);
    PKCS12 p12 = new PKCS12();
    p12.Password = password;

    Hashtable attributes = GetAttributes();
    p12.AddCertificate(new X509Certificate(rawcert), attributes);
    p12.AddPkcs8ShroudedKeyBag(subjectKey, attributes);

    return p12.GetBytes();
```

Comment: I wildly guessed at this addition 'var san = new SubjectAltNameExtension(new string[0], new string[1] { "DNS:localhost" }, new string[1] { "IP:127.0.0.1" }, new string[1] { "URI:https://localhost" }); cb.Extensions.Add(san);' which results in the error _System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var san = new SubjectAltNameExtension(new string[0], new string[1] { "localhost" }, new string[0], new string[0]); 
cb.Extensions.Add(san);
```

I tested this in Jexus Manager,

https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/blob/master/JexusManager.Features.Certificates/SelfCertificateDialog.cs